# Find link href value # and add class

Tags: jquery, href

i am facing a problem. In my project some href value has a link and some are #.when i trying to mouse hover then css mouse property cursor pointer. I want to add class when a href value are # so that after mouse hover cursor default  I want to find all link href which value are #.

if href value is # then add class else remove class on every page change.

i am trying to  solve but something mistake that i am not find...

here is my code

```
$('body').on('change', function() {

   $(this).find('[href="#"]').addClass('cusrorDefault');

}
```

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: `$('body').on('change', function() {` need to be `$('body').on('load', function() {`. there is nothing like `body onchange`

Comment: Why JavaScript, why an extra class? Why not use the `[href="#"]` selector directly in your stylesheet to achieve this?

Comment: thanks for your reply.. actually i never think about selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use **jQuery** Using **CSS**, you can easily solution this problem in all pages

```css
a[href="#"]
{
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: default;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Link</a>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Link</a>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer . but i didn't want to disable all event in element. just want to change cursor pointer property. i find a solution using css selector . thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a specific reason to use `jquery`, use `css`:

```
a[href="#"] {
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution.+1. deleted my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').each(function(){
     var href = $(this).attr("href");
     if(href == "#"){
        $(this).addClass('cusrorDefault');
     }else{
        $(this).removeClass('cusrorDefault');
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i find a solution using css selector